# Sequential Workflow Library on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, workflow-foundation

It's possible to host a Sequential Workflow Library dll (NOT SHAREPOINT Sequential Workflow Library) on sharepoint?
How can i do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean Custom Workflow created in the Visual Studio, Yes you can do it, SharePoint just acts as a Hosting Environment for the Workflow.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a difference between an ASP.NET Workflow and a SharePoint workflow. If my memory serves me correctly there is a different manager object used with the ASP.NET version to handle the situation where multiple requests are coming in.